# magenrto overriding a frontend template file

Tags: magento

I need to override the frontend onepage checkout shipping.phtml template. In my project default shipping.phtml has override once. Now i need to override it again. I tried the following code;

config.xml

```
<frontend>
            <routers>
                <one>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>TEST_one</module>
                        <frontName>one</frontName>
                    </args>
                </one>
            </routers>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <one>
                        <file>test/one.xml</file>
                    </one>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
```

one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="checkout_onepage_shipping">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>test/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

But this is not working. I am unable to override. Nothing is changing according to new shipping.phtml file.

Can anyone help me to solve this please.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue. The reason for this was the modules load alphabetically. So my module was loading before the third party module. So to solve this there are two solutions;

1. Rename my module after the other third party module alphabetically.
2. Use `<depends>`.

So i edited my module.xml file using `<depends>` based on `Mage_Checkout`.

Now it is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

To override shipping.phtml,Please go to following path:-

app/design/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/layout/local.xml

Open this file and in place of shipping.phtml write the name of localfile_shipping.phtml and put this file infront of shipping.phtml and do the needfull changes in local file.

I override payment.phtml file using the above code.